# xgboostclassifier prediction error after saving the model and restoring it

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata, xgboost, data-science-model

I have trained a xgboost model and during training, the prediction works fine. But if I stop the script and start a restoring script to restore and predict, then for the same test dataset I get every data classified into one class. The weird part is that, even with the first prediction, i restore the model as shown below,

```
X = df.drop(['label'], axis=1)
y = df['label']
training_count = 0

X_train, test_data, y_train, test_label = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=7)
model = XGBClassifier(learning_rate=0.5, n_estimators=250, max_depth= 5)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
model.save_model('trained_model_full')

#validation  

model = XGBClassifier(learning_rate=0.5, n_estimators=250, max_depth= 5)
booster = xgb.Booster()
booster.load_model('trained_model_full')
model._Booster = booster
model._le = LabelEncoder().fit(test_label)
start = time.time()
pred = model.predict(test_data)
end = time.time()
```

The above code works and gives me 99% accuracy. But if I remove the training part and just restore it like below, then it fails to work. I get 50% accuracy.

```
X = df.drop(['label'], axis=1)
y = df['label']
training_count = 0

X_train, test_data, y_train, test_label = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=7)

#validation

model = XGBClassifier(learning_rate=0.5, n_estimators=250, max_depth= 5)
booster = xgb.Booster()
booster.load_model('trained_model_full')
model._Booster = booster
model._le = LabelEncoder().fit(test_label)
start = time.time()
pred = model.predict(test_data)
end = time.time()
```

This is a strange issue. Have anyone come across something like this? if so could you help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use joblib to save the model:

```
import joblib    

#This one saves the model
joblib.dump(model, 'trained_model_full') 
#This one loads the model
model= joblib.load('trained_model_full')
```

Comment: Awesome. It works now. And with this approach one doesn't need to invoke the booster seperately. Thanks